# Calling upon a text file with multiple numbers that serve different purposes to create a store and sales bar graph

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment on Online GDB that reads sales information for a chain of stores from a text file. The program needs to display a "Bar Graph" comparing each stores sales. I need to create each bar by displaying a row of asterisks, that each represents each $100 of the sale.

I need to use these numbers

```
1234 405.00
2313 675.23
4324 255.99
987 801.45
1979 615.67
8989 120.98
7325 204.05
123 1034.56
9283 400.24
4570 567.70
7969 445.68
5218 757.27
8382 955.51
681 532.40
8645 729.08
```

Each pair represents the store and sale.

The output needs to show something like this.

```
  Sales Chart:
Store #    Sales
1234:      ****
2313:      ******
```

This is the code I have been working on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
// libary of varibles 
int main(){
  string line;
  int asterisk;
  int number;
  int y;
  ifstream infile;
  // varibles for code 
  infile.open("salesinfo.txt");
  //opens file
  if(infile){ 
      cout << "Sales chart" << endl;
      cout << "Stores \t Sales" << endl;
      //seperating our stores and sales

      while(infile >> number){
          cout << number << "\t";
          asterisk = number / 100;
          for(int y =0; y < asterisk; y++){
              cout << "*";
              // math for asterik and seperating the stores and sales
          }
          cout<<endl;
      }
      infile.close();
      // closing file

  }
  else{
      cout << "Error";
      //error if file is not open 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I get this output

```
 Sales Chart
Stores   Sales
1234    ************
405     ****
```

I have two problems here that I need help on. The first one is that I don't know why it doesn't output all the numbers. The second problem is that it is not separating these two variables. As you can see it evaluated the * for both 1234 and 405 and I need the asterisks to replace the 405 by **** next to the 1234. I simply don't understand how to treat these two pairs on each text file line diffrently. 
Your help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You only read a single int at a time into number. You need to read an int for the store and a double for the sales.

Comment: I did what you said and I managed to get all the numbers displaying but then it found asterisks for all the numbers. I don't know how to separate the two can you further explain, please.